# ASP.NET Core find a service in IServiceProvider that matches a UnderlyingSystemType

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method which accepts a list of domain events which implement the interface `IDomainEvent`. What I'm trying to do is get the underlying type of the `IDomainEvent` and then use IServiceProvider to get a service matching the underlying system type.

For example, this works;

```
TicketCreatedEvent event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<TicketCreatedEvent>));
// Where _serviceProvider is ASP.NET Cores standard DI provider.
```

But this doesn't as the event object is created as an interface rather than it's concrete type.

```
IDomainEvent event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<TicketCreatedEvent>));
```

I know I can retrieve the underlying type by using `event.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType` but I cannot figure out how to then use this within the `_serviceProvider.GetService()`, I thought I could have done the following, but it isn't valid;

```
IDomainEvent event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
Type type = event.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<type>));
```

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Sorry, it seems I missed some important information out of my question.

In my example above, the `event` is created just before the `_serviceProvider` is used, by in reality the event is passed to a method on an EventRaiser object, like this;

```
public static Raise<T>(T args) {
    var service = (IEventHandler<T>) _locator.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<T>));
}

TicketCreatedEvent event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
Raise(event); // Works

IDomainEvent event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
Raise(event); // Doesn't work as it cannot locate the service
```

Where `T` is created using the interface, the service cannot be located, it only works if `T` is directly of the concrete implementation.

To help solving the problem, here is my complete `DomainEventRaiser` class. There are two important methods, the first is `Raise', which will raise an event right away without being deferred. The second is`RaisedDeferred`which accepts a list of events and handles them,`RaisedDeferred` will be called when events need to be deferred, such as after a domain object has been persists.

```
public class DomainEventsRaiser
    {
        [ThreadStatic] //so that each thread has its own callbacks
        private static List<Delegate> _actions;

        // ASP.NET Core DI Service Provider
        private static IServiceProvider _locator;

        /// <summary>
        /// Lets the event raiser know what DI provider to use to find event handlers
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="provider"></param>
        public static void RegisterProvider(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _locator = provider;
        }

        public static void Register2<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            if (_actions == null)
            {
                _actions = new List<Delegate>();
            }

            _actions.Add(callback);
        }

        public static void ClearCallbacks()
        {
            _actions = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Accepts a list of events, usually deferred events
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="events">list of events to handle</param>
        public static void RaiseDeferred(IList<IDomainEvent> events)
        {
            if (events != null)
            {
                foreach (IDomainEvent ev in events)
                {
                    Type eventType = ev.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
                    Type genericHandlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>);
                    Type constructedHandlerType = genericHandlerType.MakeGenericType(eventType);
                    var service =  _locator.GetService(constructedHandlerType);
                    constructedHandlerType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(service, null);

                    if (service != null)
                    {
                        service.Handle(args); // Cannot resolve symbol 'Handle'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles an event right away
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">event arguments</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">the event to handle</typeparam>
        public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
        {     
            if (_locator != null)
            {   
                var service = (IEventHandler<T>) _locator.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<T>));
                if (service != null)
                {
                    service.Handle(args);
                }
            }

            if (_actions != null)
            {
                foreach (var action in _actions)
                {
                    if (action is Action<T>)
                    {
                        ((Action<T>) action)(args);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first and second snippet are identical as far as serviceProvider part is concerned so how can one work and another not

Comment: Sorry, I had completely missed important information out of the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
IDomainEvent @event = new TicketCreatedEvent();
Type eventType = @event.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
Type genericHandlerType = typeof(IEventHandler<>);
Type constructedHandlerType = genericHandlerType.MakeGenericType(eventType);
var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(constructedHandlerType);
```

I assume you're registering your handlers in Startup.cs like:

```
services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<TicketCreatedEvent>, TicketCreatedEventHandler>();
```

For more info, see [How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection).

Comment: Thanks, I think that looks like it might work. I also need to cast the service to the correct type. var service = (IEventHandler<T>) _locator.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<T>)); How would I cast the service using your example?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information in order to provide a good answer. Generally speaking, at this point you can either continue using reflection and do something like `constructedHandlerType.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(service, null);`, or maybe use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) if you really want concrete behavior.

Comment: I have added my complete DomainRaiser class to the end of my question. In the method `RaiseDeferred` the call to `service.Handle(args)` results in a `Cannot resolve symbol 'Handle`.